# How can I add additional options to drive mount notifications?

Tags: gnome, usb, mount, notification, gnome-shell-extension

When I plug in a USB drive or a USB stick, I would like to add more options (like rsync files OR backup to device, ...) to the popup menu. When one option is clicked, I'd simply like to start a shell script.

I was poking in dconf editor under `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.autorun-x-content-start-app` but not sure what to do there.

I'm using gnome-shell 3.12.2 and higher.

Any advice is very welcome!

Comment: You may be able to use udev as per (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/how-to-execute-a-shellscript-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device).  An application to allow custom actions is Cuttlefish - see (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/cuttlefish-set-actions-reactions-automate-ubuntu/) but that may take some effort to install at present.

Comment: Thx, going this way looks like a bunch of work.. I'll check if dconf-editor can help me here with this array of tasks in there.